# MDX - Filter members using AND operator in Query designer or otherwise

Tags: mdx, operator-keyword

I have the following table:

```
ID Column A  
1    ValA 
1    ValA 
1    Special 
2    ValA 
3    ValA
```

I need to return only IDs which has a Special value in Column A. So the output would be:

```
ID Column A  
1   ValA 
1   ValA 
1   Special
```

I thought that one way would be to use the MDX operator but there is very little documentation on it. I am a real beginner of MDX.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Exists` function, as [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144936.aspx) and then a cross join should do what you want, as the cross join within a dimension uses autoexists and thus does not really do a full cross join, but only a kind of inner join, resulting in tuples really existing in the dimension table.

Assuming the table that you show in your question is a dimension table, and the attributes are named `[Your Dimension].[Id]` and `[Your Dimension].[A]`, you would use

```
Exists([Your Dimension].[Id].[Id].Members, [Your Dimension].[A].[Special])
*
[Your Dimension].[A].[A].Members
```